# Concatenate unknown amount of argument arrays. Throw duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, concatenation

A functions takes an unknown amount of arrays as arguments. These arrays could consist of nested arrays too. I need to throw duplicates and return one new array (without duplicates). The array elements should not appear in a sorted way but in their order, they stood in their original array.

I used `map` to push every array into one new array.
I used `reduce` to concat the arrays.
I used `Set` to throw duplicates.

**It worked only in this case**

```
uniteUnique([[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4]]);
```

**I don't know, why it does not works in these cases:**

```
Argument Fail1 // uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);

Argument Fail2 // uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]]);
Argument Fail3 // uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1]);
```

**This is my code**

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  let test = [];
  arr.map(function(argu) {
    test.push(argu);
  }, []);

  let flat = test.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  });

  let unique = new Set(flat);

  console.log(unique);
}
```

What is wrong? It would be very kind, if anybody could tell me, why my code does not work with Argument Fail 1-3.

**Error thrown in these cases is:**

> **return a.concat(b); /n
>                 TypeError: a.concat is not a function**

**Expected Output:** 
`uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1])` should return `[1, 3, 2, 5, 4]`.
`uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]])` should return `[1, 3, 2, [5], [4]]`.
`uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1])` should return `[1, 2, 3, 5]`.
`uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1], [6, 7, 8])` should return `[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8]`.

Comment: Add an initial value of `[]` to `.reduce`. It is failing cause it is doing `1.concat` in the first testcase

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You are passing multiple arguments but the function has only one arguments to receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your function signature takes only one parameter, `arr`. And here you're passing just one:

> uniteUnique([[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4]]);

That's why it works. Where In the failure cases, you pass multiple arrays:

> uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);

Therefore it takes just `[1, 3, 2]`, ignoring the others, and trying to reducing the first, starting from the first element `1`, that is clearly not an array, and it doesn't have `concat`.

What you want to do, is changing your method signature – and removing the `map` that is useless:

```
function uniteUnique(...test) {

  let flat = test.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  });

  let unique = new Set(flat);

  console.log(unique);
}
```

Using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you're putting in `test` all the arguments as array.

BTW you can also use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) where implemented (or a polyfill where not):

```
const flatUnique = (...test) => new Set(test.flat())
```

And, if you want to have an array instead of a `Set`, you can get it back using spread syntax again:

```
const flatUnique = (...test) => [...new Set(test.flat())]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could take a check for the item if it is an array and flat this array as well.

```js
const
    flat = array => array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(Array.isArray(a) ? flat(a) : a), []),
    uniteUnique = (...array) => [...new Set(flat(array))];

console.log(uniteUnique([[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4]]));
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]]));
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**flat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const uniteUnique = (array) => [...new Set(array.flat(Infinity))];

console.log(uniteUnique([[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4]]));
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]]));
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```